cómo saber cuál versión de Java EE/Jakarta EE estoy utilizando en Eclipse 2023-12?
Uso Eclipse 2023-12 y tengo JavaSE-17, pero al cambiar de perspectiva a Java EE/Jakarta EE no sé cómo ver la versión.

En Eclipse puedes ver la versión de Java que estás usando en cierto proyecto dándole clic derecho al proyecto -> Properties ->Java Compiler. Si tienes configurada una versión específica para el proyecto, te aparecerá ahí.

Por otro lado, si no tienes una versión especificada, te aparecerá algo como lo siguiente:

Y en dicho caso, podrás ver la versión dando clic en Configure Workspace Settings, en donde aparecerá (de todas las versiones que tienes) la versión por default para tus proyectos.

Espero que te sirva.
